# How to insert range type data in typeorm

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

postgresql / typeorm / nestjs

I am reporting an error when inserting data using typeorm,
Mainly because the rangetype is not converted to a string

```
@Entity()
export class Test {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @Column('numrange', { array: true })
    price: number[];
}
```

```
this.entityRepository.save({
    price: [100,200]
})
```

```
logger: INSERT INTO "test" ( "id", "price", ) VALUES ( DEFAULT, $1 ) RETURNING "id" -- PARAMETERS: [[100,200]]

postgresql: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["
```

Answer (score 0):

in pg driver it is

```
pool.query(
  `
    INSERT INTO test
      (title,numbers_range)
      VALUES ($1,$2)
  `,
  ["test", JSON.stringify([100, 200])],
);
```

> PS:
>
> [100, 200] include 200
>
> [100, 200) not include 200

OR

```
pool.query(
  `
    INSERT INTO test
      (title,numbers_range)
      VALUES ($1,$2)
  `,
  ["test", "[100,200)"],
);
```

in typeorm it can be

```
this.entityRepository.save({
    price: JSON.stringify([100,200])
})
```

OR

```
this.entityRepository.save({
    price: "[100,200)"
})
```

from doc
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-INDEXING

```
CREATE TABLE reservation (room int, during tsrange);
INSERT INTO reservation VALUES
    (1108, '[2010-01-01 14:30, 2010-01-01 15:30)');
```